# HP e-Print & Exchange/Outlook email: How can I get the header of the email to print along with the body & attachments?

Tags: printing

I need to copy my elderly mother on email threads for her information. However, since she cannot "do email", I send her email to her HP ePrint capable multi-function printer, replicating "snail mail".

However, only the body and attachments of the email are printed; the header (ie: date, to/from/cc, subject, etc) is not printed. This makes it very difficult for her to understand the context of the body of the email.

Is there a way I can configure her printer or the HP printing cloud to also print the email header?

If it matters, I am sending email via Exchange/Outlook.

Any help would be greatly appreciated! Thank you!